# Предлагаю объединить метки "сложноподчиненное" и "спп".

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Предлагаю объявить метку "сложноподчиненное" синонимом основной метки "спп". Это будет логично, так как уже существуют метки "ссп" и "бсп"."

P.S. Cамому не удается (очевидно, нет прав).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метки объединены, синоним [создан](https://rus.stackexchange.com/tags/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BF/synonyms).

Вы можете самостоятельно предлагать синонимы меток по достижении 1250 баллов репутации. Если, на ваш взгляд, какие-то метки стоит объединить, пожалуйста, создавайте соответствующие вопросы на Мете.